# Create random string in ABAP CDS view

Tags: random, abap, opensql, cds

I would like to replace some ABAP logic with ABAP-CDS views. We don't have a HANA DB ( yet ) - so no SQL Script. Is there a way to create a random String with a defined length in ABAP-CDS?

This is a preparation for our HANA DB migration and should replace the function module "GENERAL_GET_RANDOM_STRING".

I want to "push down" as much logic as possible to the database, because we have about 16.000.000 entries where we need to enter a random string. And if this is created via Database this would be much faster.

Comment: Could you please elobarate in how far do you want to replace ABAP logic with a CDS? Would you like to "push down" former function module code to the database or provide standardised data access via OData to replace proprietary RFC connections? In case of the latter you could select a constant, even empty string in you CDS definition and overwrite it in the Data Provision Class (DPC) EXT method. Please provide a minimal example if possible.

Comment: I don't see that function module in my system and hence the length of the random string field length. Can you use functions like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or TO_TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: @konstantin - currently I don't have any CDS definition. I just want to see my possibilities if this is possible or not. If not I'll stay with an ABAP solution. DPC EXT method is, as far as I know, only available for OData Services, is it? I would use this cds in my normal abap report.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

Generate a GUID and truncate it to the length of your random string requirements.

Alternatively if your string is not entirely random and you have an array of values you want to randomly pick from. Select that list with a new column of generated GUID. Sort that list using the guid, pick the top one. In the back of my mind I have a nagging doubt that I'm missing a step from this one. Perhaps the GUID has to be trunctated also in this scenario.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In general a good idea, but how can I do this in an CDS View? - As said in the question, I'd like to push as much logic as possible to the database.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is a way with a table function but you are no better off than just doing it in ABAP I'd say. I was thinking there would be some way to leverage SYSUUID but not in CDS apparently.